# Trying to understand pointers and threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I am fairly new to C and trying to understand threads and pointers. As far as i know, this line creates a thread

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
```

The fourth arg is taking the argument for the pointer function `(void *)t`, and this is a pointer to the address of variable `t` which is a `long` type? And the pointer function takes the argument of void pointer to a variable, which is `(void *)t`.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 20

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
       }
     }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

After that, I changed the pointer function and the `pthread_create` to this:

```
{
   long taskid;
   sleep(1);
   taskid = *(long *)threadid;
   printf("Hello from thread %ld\n", taskid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

 rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *) &t);
```

So now the void pointer is still pointing to the address of variable `t`?

And  `*(long *)threadid` is de-referencing the variable `t`?
And it outputs the final value of `t` in all threads.

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, if I misunderstood somewhere I appreciate any advice. My question is for the `(void *)t` and `(void *) &t`, they are both pointers to the address of variable `t`, and I read pointers can only be point to addresses but not values, so why is the `(void *)t` outputting the incrementing values of `t`? `taskid = *(long *)threadid;` And if I just do `taskid = threadid` it prints out the address of `t`, what does `*(long *)` do? The `*` outside the brackets is de-referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a type in brackets before something is casting that value into that data type. So in your examples `(void *) t` converts the value of `t` from a `long` to a `void *`. This is done because the `pthread_create` is expecting a pointer.

Putting a `&` in front of something gets the address of it. So `&t` gets the address of `t`. It's then being cast to `void *` as described above, although it isn't really needed as any pointer will be automatically cast to `void *` if required.

So in the first version of your code you're passing the actual value of `t` into your thread by casting it to make it look like it is a pointer and then casting it back again inside the thread to get the `long` value.

The second version is passing a pointer to `t` in, so each thread will print out the value of `t` at the time the reach this line:

```
taskid = *(long *)threadid;
```

Comment: taskid = *(long *)threadid; so on this line i am casting it back to long, but since it's a pointer to t, i have to use * outside the brackets to get the value, and casting (long *) because it is a pointer? Otherwise it wouldn't work if i just cast (long) because t is a pointer?

Comment: Not quite. You're casting it to `long *` and then dereferencing that. You can't dereference `void *` pointers.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the explanation, i understand it better now :)

Answer (score 2):

To get an address of a variable you have to use `&`.

`(void*)t` does not get the address of `t`. It takes the value of `t`, and treats that value as a `void*` value instead. So you have a pointer to memory address 0, 1, 2, ... up to NUM_THREADS-1.

You can't use these pointers because they don't point to valid addresses. But you can treat them as numbers again by using `(long)threadid`.

The only reason you need to make the type `void*` is because that's what pthreads uses as the parameter to the thread function. If you used `void *PrintHello(long threadid)` then you would get an error when calling `pthread_create`, which would say that the function had the wrong type.

Comment: So in the second example, i have to cast (long *)threadid because i'm passing in the pointer to t, in other words the address of t?

Comment: @aalang Yes. I hope you also understand why it prints the final value in all threads.

Comment: I kinda get why, but is it because i called sleep(1), and by the time it finishes sleep, the t value is already the final value, and so it only starts assigning taskid to the threadid?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. (I'm not sure what "it only starts assigning taskid to the threadid" means but the rest of what you said is correct)

Comment: I mean after it sleeps, then only executes the rest of the code from taskid = threadid, which by then is already final value